# Make custom app available on 'Activities' of Ubuntu

Tags: gnome-shell, activities-overview, ubuntu-make

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and I just installed eclipse through `umake`. But there is a problem.

I can find the directory and the executable file of eclipse in `~/.local/share/umake/ide/eclipse`. And I succeeded in launching it by executing `./eclipse` in that dir.

But when I hit <kbd>Super</kbd> on my keyboard and tried to launch eclipse by typing its name on the search bar, it failed. When It seems that there is no such app.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by creating a `.desktop` launcher for Eclipse in your `~/.local/share/applications/` directory.

1. Create a new file, say `eclipse.desktop` in your `~/.local/share/applications/` directory. You can do that by running the following in Terminal

   ```
   touch ~/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
   ```
2. Open this file with a text-editor, for example by running

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
   ```
3. Add the following lines to this file and save the file

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Comment=A comment to describe the application
   Terminal=false
   Name=Eclipse
   Exec=/home/YOUR-USERNAME/.local/share/umake/ide/eclipse/eclipse
   Type=Application
   Icon=eclipse
   NoDisplay=false
   ```

   In place of `YOUR-USERNAME` put your actual username.